# Automapper fails to translate generic lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have two collections of the following classes that I want to map:

```
 public class Client_Crime_ViewModel
    {
       public Client_Crime_ViewModel() { }

        public Client_Crime_ViewModel(CrimeIncident ci)
        {
            Id = ci.Id;
            CaseNumber = ci.CaseNumber;
            DateOfIncident = ci.DateOfIncident;
            Description = ci.Description;
        }

        public Int64 Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Case Number")]
        public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Date of Incident")]
        public string DateOfIncident { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }



public class CrimeIncident
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string CaseNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public string DateOfIncident { get; set; }

        public CrimeIncident() { }

        public CrimeIncident(string caseNumber, string dateOfIncident, string description)
        {
            CaseNumber = caseNumber;
            Description = description;
            DateOfIncident = dateOfIncident;
        }
    }
```

I have tried mapping in both of the following ways:

Method 1:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Client_Crime_ViewModel>, List<CrimeIncident>>();
List<Client_Crime_ViewModel> cvmList = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<System.Collections.Generic.List<Client_Crime_ViewModel>>(rb.Form["CrimeCollection"]);
List<CrimeIncident> ciList = Mapper.Map<List<Client_Crime_ViewModel>, List<CrimeIncident>>(cvmList);
```

Method 2:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<List<Client_Crime_ViewModel>, List<CrimeIncident>>();
List<Client_Crime_ViewModel> cvmList = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode<System.Collections.Generic.List<Client_Crime_ViewModel>>(rb.Form["CrimeCollection"]);
List<CrimeIncident> ciList = Mapper.Map<List<CrimeIncident>>(cvmList);
```

Both methods fail. Debugging reveals that although the element count for `cvmList` is `> 0`,  the element count for ciList remains at `0`.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a map for a list, just map the entities.

Comment: +1. This is the #1 thing I find myself helping other developers with when using Automapper.

Comment: I figured this out about 30 seconds after posting the question. Thanks.  Only started using the tooltoday... so yeah...  They could probably put an example of how to map lists on their welcome / homepage if you ask me.